# WooCommerce get Stripe Fee of Order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get the fees of my orders by code.
There are two possible fees: stripe and paypal.

The Stripe Fee is saved within the order meta: _stripe_fee

I need to get the amount that's in there.
Or: all of the possible fees (paypal and stripe).

While I could just get the meta field, I really don't want to hardcode the fieldname.

Is there a way to get alle the fees for an order?

I tried to get it like that:

```
$order = wc_get_order( 8012 );

var_dump($order->get_fees());
```

But the Array is empty.

But

`var_dump($order)`

Shows that there is a stripe fee (and the backend and database also says so)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, theoretically `$order->fees()` should return fees. It does this by returning the array `fee_line`. Unfortunately neither Stripe nor Paypal appear to write to that`fee_line`. Instead they write to the meta property.

This doesn't stop you from rolling your own function to return either Stripe or Paypal fees though:

```
function get_order_fees(WCOrder $order) {

    switch(true) {
        // get fees from Stripe, if exists
        case $fees = $order->get_meta("_stripe_fee");
            break;
        // get fees from Paypal, if exists
        case $fees = $order->get_meta("_paypal_transaction_fee"):
           break;
        // otherwise fee is 0
        default:
            $fees = 0;
            break;
    }

    return $fees;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a more general solution. Like > is there a Fee (either Stripe or Paypal) and if so, give it to me, without getting the meta. What is the get_fees() function even for...

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation for the `get_fees()` method. Where did you find it?

Comment: Found here: [link]https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#methods[/link]

Comment: I've done some research and updated the answer. See whether that helps.

Comment: Your are great! Thanks :)

Comment: @nuriye You're most welcome! If the answer worked for you please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Where/How do you use this great function ?